How to display Dropdown selected text in a Text element in Unity UI without scripting?
I'm building a UI in Unity and want to display the currently selected text from a Dropdown element in a separate Text element. I want to achieve this without writing any C# scripts, ideally using the built-in On Value Changed event.
I'm not sure how to reference both the Text element and the selected Dropdown text within the On Value Changed event.
Can someone please provide a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this using only the Unity Inspector?
